# Clean up string extracted from csv file

Tags: python, ruby, csv, export-to-csv

I am extracting certain data from a csv file using Ruby and I want to cleanup the extracted string by removing the unwanted characters.

This is how I extract the data so far:

```
CSV.foreach(data_file, :encoding => 'windows-1251:utf-8', :headers => true) do |row|

    #create an array for each page
    page_data = []
    #For each page, get the data we are interested in and save it to the page_data
    page_data.push(row['dID'])
    page_data.push(row['xTerm'])

    pages_to_import.push(page_data)
```

Then I output the csv file with the extracted data

The output extracted is exactly as it is on the csv data file:

```
| ID    |  Term                                   |
|-------|-----------------------------------------|
| 13241 |  @@106#107#my@@106#term@@           |
| 13345 |  @@63#hello@@                           |
| 11436 |  @@55#rock@@20#my@@10015#18#world@@ |
```

However, My desired result that I want to achieve is:

```
| ID    |  Term                                   |
|-------|-----------------------------------------|
| 13241 |  my, term                               |
| 13345 |  hello                                  |
| 11436 |  rock, my, world                        |
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Libraries that Im using:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'cgi'
require 'csv'
```

Comment: regexp seems like a good candidate to resolve it

Comment: What have you tried? It's a lot better for you, and easier for us, if you show us what you've attempted, tell us what's wrong with it, and then we can tweak it, rather than someone write something totally unrelated to what you're doing and you try to shoehorn it into your code.

Comment: nor sure where to start with it to be honest first time using ruby!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regular expression, I'd do:

```
%w[
  @@106#107#term1@@106#term2@@
  @@63#term1@@
  @@55#term1@@20#term2@@10015#18#term3@@
  @@106#107#my@@106#term@@
  @@63#hello@@
  @@55#rock@@20#my@@10015#18#world@@
].map{ |str|
  str.scan(/[^@#]+?)(?=@/)
}
# => [["term1", "term2"], ["term1"], ["term1", "term2", "term3"], ["my", "term"], ["hello"], ["rock", "my", "world"]]
```

My `str` is the equivalent of the contents of your `row['xTerm']`.

The regular expression `/[^@#]+?(?=@)/` searches for patterns in `str` that don't contain `#` or `@` and end with `@`.

From the garbage in the string, and your comment that you're using Nokogiri and CSV, and because you didn't show your input data as CSV or HTML, I have to wonder if you're not mangling the incoming data somehow, and trying to wiggle out of it in post-processing. If so, show us what you're actually doing and maybe we can help you get clean data to start.

Comment: what does this mean?: undefined method `map'

Comment: Just what it says, the object you have `.map` chained to doesn't define a method called `map`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your terms are bookended and separated by `@@` and consist of one or more numbers followed by the actual term separated by `#`. To get the terms into an array:

```
row['xTerm'].split('@@')[1..-1].map { |term| term.split(?#)[-1] }
```

Then you can `join` or do whatever you want with it.

Comment: what if my terms are not called term1 and term2 etc. but they are certain words. PLEASE SEE NEW VERSION

Comment: Did you read my code? It doesn't have anything to do with the string `'term'`.